# Pandas adding different rows based on multiple column/row criteria

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Say I have a grocery store and have a daily running list of inventory for each fruit. I need to update the daily inventory from a dataframe of daily spoilage totals. How do I take the ending inventory from 8/31/2018 and add it the spoilage from the night of 9/1/2018 to get the beginning inventory for 9/1/2018.

My daily fruit sales are in a consolidated like this.

```
Fruit CurrentDate  DailyFruitSpoilage
0  Apple   2018-08-29  -10
1  Apple   2018-08-30  -20
2  Apple   2018-08-31  -30
3  Apple   2018-09-01  -40
4  Orange  2018-08-29  -10
5  Orange  2018-08-30  -20
6  Orange  2018-08-31  -30
7  Orange  2018-09-01  -40
```

My inventory table is like this:

```
Fruit CurrentDate  DailyEndingInventory  BeginningFruitInventory
0  Apple   2018-08-28  1000               1050
1  Apple   2018-08-29  900                990
2  Apple   2018-08-30  870                880
3  Apple   2018-08-31  820                840
4  Orange  2018-08-28  1000               1050
5  Orange  2018-08-29  900                990
6  Orange  2018-08-30  820                870
7  Orange  2018-08-31  750                790
```

So to get the orange inventory for 9/1/2018, I want to take my Orange inventory from 8/31 (750) and add to it my spoilage of Oranges (-40) from the night of 9/1/2018 to get my beginning Orange inventory of 710 when I start the day on 9/1/2018. The The DailyEndingInventory and DailyFruitSpoilage come from a database, I'm trying to calculate BeginningFruitInventory.

My first thought was merge based on fruit and date but by doing that the rows are offset by 1 in the past. If that makes sense.

```
8/30's DailyEndingInventory + 8/31's DailyFruitSpoilage = 8/31's BeginningFruitInventory
```

In a nutshell how do I add columns when the data I need is on different rows?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: I would like to generate the column with BeginningFruitInventory. But I can't seem to figure out how to make calculation across rows and columns at once.

Comment: Your input can not match your output date

Comment: @Wen How exactly do you mean. I don't quite understand?

Comment: It doesn't make sense that your `BeginningFruitInventory` for one day is not simply the `EndingFruitInventory` for the previous day of the same fruit in your current inventory table. Exactly what information do you start with? It's very unclear as to what information you have, and what information you may have miscalculated.

Comment: @ALollz I am given EndingFruitInventory and DailyFruitSpoilage from a database. For this example pretend that the spoilage is counted and entered into the database the following morning prior to opening. So the date is offset by 1 which is why I can't simply merge on date and fruit and add the columns together. Most sincere apologies that its confusing. Sometimes its hard to come up with accurate fictitious examples.

Comment: `-50` is wrong... It should be `-30`... right?

Comment: @I'-'I Apologies, you're on the right trail. It would be -40 the spoilage counted on 9/1. (not 8/31) I edited the original post. Thank you!

Comment: Provide Good examples if you want to receive answers. `Orange  2018-08-30  820                870` How 870? From the top, Orange 1000 `-10` = 990; 900`-20` = 880(not 870);820``-30``=790....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your data:

```
data_1 = {'Fruit': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Orange'],
        'CurrentDate': ['2018-08-29', '2018-08-30', '2018-08-31', '2018-09-01', '2018-08-29', '2018-08-30', '2018-08-31', '2018-09-01'],
        'DailyFruitSpoilage': [-10, -20, -30, -40, -10, -20, -30, -40]}

data_2 = {'Fruit': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Orange'],
        'CurrentDate': ['2018-08-29', '2018-08-30', '2018-08-31', '2018-09-01', '2018-08-29', '2018-08-30', '2018-08-31', '2018-09-01'],
        'DailyEndingInventory': [1000, 900, 870, 820, 1000, 900, 820, 750]}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2)
```

Cast dates accordingly and create a date offset:

```
df_1['CurrentDate'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df_1['CurrentDate'], freq='D')
df_1['Date'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df_1['CurrentDate'], freq='D')
df_2['Date'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df_2['CurrentDate'], freq='D')
df_2['Date'] += 1
```

Then merge the data_frames with a lag:

```
df_3 = df_1.merge(df_2, on=['Date','Fruit'], suffixes=('','_lag'), how='right')
```

Calculate the column differences and then shift accordingly:

```
df_3['BeginningInventory'] = df_3['DailyFruitSpoilage'] + df_3['DailyEndingInventory']

df_3.BeginningInventory = df_3.BeginningInventory.shift(+1)
```

And you return a `BeginningInventory` column as such:

```
Index   Fruit CurrentDate  DailyFruitSpoilage       Date CurrentDate_lag  DailyEndingInventory  BeginningInventory
0   Apple  2018-08-30               -20.0 2018-08-30      2018-08-29                  1000                 NaN
1   Apple  2018-08-31               -30.0 2018-08-31      2018-08-30                   900               980.0
2   Apple  2018-09-01               -40.0 2018-09-01      2018-08-31                   870               870.0
3  Orange  2018-08-30               -20.0 2018-08-30      2018-08-29                  1000               830.0
4  Orange  2018-08-31               -30.0 2018-08-31      2018-08-30                   900               980.0
5  Orange  2018-09-01               -40.0 2018-09-01      2018-08-31                   820               870.0
6   Apple         NaT                 NaN 2018-09-02      2018-09-01                   820               780.0
7  Orange         NaT                 NaN 2018-09-02      2018-09-01                   750                 NaN
```

Comment: But the dates will never match as the fruit spoilage value will always need to be added to the prior day's DailyEndingInventory.

Comment: good point, I've edited originally proposed solution to use an offset and shit, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

We can use numpy arrays to slice and add them. Assuming `df` is spoilage table and `df2` is inventory table and 1050 as initial number of fruits,

```
dfj=df.join(df2.set_index(['CurrentDate','Fruit']),on=['CurrentDate','Fruit'],how='outer')
dfj=dfj.sort_values(['Fruit','CurrentDate']).reset_index(None,True)
dfj.loc[1:,'BeginningFruitInventory']=np.array(dfj.DailyEndingInventory[:-1])+np.array(dfj.DailyFruitSpoilage[1:])
dfj.BeginningFruitInventory.fillna(1050,inplace=True)
dfj
```

```
    Fruit   CurrentDate     DailyFruitSpoilage  DailyEndingInventory    BeginningFruitInventory
0   Apple   2018-08-28  NaN     1000.0  1050.0
1   Apple   2018-08-29  -10.0   900.0   990.0
2   Apple   2018-08-30  -20.0   870.0   880.0
3   Apple   2018-08-31  -30.0   820.0   840.0
4   Apple   2018-09-01  -40.0   NaN     780.0
5   Orange  2018-08-28  NaN     1000.0  1050.0
6   Orange  2018-08-29  -10.0   900.0   990.0
7   Orange  2018-08-30  -20.0   820.0   880.0
8   Orange  2018-08-31  -30.0   750.0   790.0
9   Orange  2018-09-01  -40.0   NaN     710.0
```

- Join two dataframes on CurrentDate and fruit
- Sort and reset Index
- Use np.array() to add slices of each Series without considering index
- Alternatively,  You can also reset_index after slicing them and add them normally.